# web design in javascript , php, css

Tags: html, css

I have an amateur question, is there a comprehensive software for design web site that support all web language for example html , css , php, javascript, and laravel framework and also data base and interface design from A to Z .Thank’s for your answer to this question .
excuse me guy
not just editor something like netbeans or visual studio

Comment: Are you looking for an Editor??

Comment: Yes. It's called a LAMP-stack (or WAMP-stack for Windows, MAMP-stack for Mac), and it consists of (for LAMP) Linux, Apache, MySQL,PHP (traditionally). And then you add a text-editor, personally I prefer Sublime, but there are many others.

Comment: Of course there is. Any plain text editor. You can design and code anything you want with it.

Comment: What you are looking for. Is it an editor or some tools which have all these features.

Comment: not just editor something like netbeans or visual studio

Answer (score 1):

Coda is a good alternative for beginners, with preview and plenty of language support.
https://panic.com/coda/

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try https://www.sublimetext.com/ modern editor used by most of the developers

Answer (score 0):

Btw Visual studio is an editor. There are some great editors you could find for eg. Caret(Chrome OS only), VIM, Notepad++, Atom, Code pad(Chrome OS only), Bluefish, and, Sublime. (I understand this post is very old) Also, there are online editors like Codepen.io

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).